# Hide sections label from search results

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I have a listview displayed a list of regions. This listview contains sections as well.

I want to understand how to hide sections label from search results? Or how to disable the sections from being clicked.

I want only to get the items in the list after search without sections.

[image: before search]

[image: after search]

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            ArrayList<Item> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(Item temp : countryList){
                if(temp.getTitle().toString().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())) {
                    tempList.add(temp);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hani", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            CountryAdapter adapter = new CountryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), tempList);
            lvCountry.setAdapter(adapter);
            //adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are using a SearchView and ListView with your itens inside you can always use the method below on the SearchView to filter you adapter

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Inside of your custom adapter you will need to

```
public class SearchAddressAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private List<AddressItemModel> items;
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(valueFilter==null) {

        valueFilter=new ValueFilter();
    }

    return valueFilter;
}
private class ValueFilter extends Filter {

    //Invoked in a worker thread to filter the data according to the constraint.
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
        if(constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0){
            List<AddressItemModel> filterList=new ArrayList<AddressItemModel>();
            for(int i=0;i<mStringFilterList.size();i++){
                if((mStringFilterList.get(i).getTitle().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                    AddressItemModel contacts = new AddressItemModel();
                    contacts.setTitle(mStringFilterList.get(i).getTitle());
                    filterList.add(contacts);
                }
            }
            results.count=filterList.size();
            results.values=filterList;
        }else{
            results.count=mStringFilterList.size();
            results.values=mStringFilterList;
        }
        return results;
    }


    //Invoked in the UI thread to publish the filtering results in the user interface.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  FilterResults results) {
        items = (ArrayList<AddressItemModel>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

That is pretty much it :)